# How to loop through multiple foreach loops and insert data into the database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel

Good morning bros, how are you?
i am having an issue with this loop

```
$users = User::all(); 
foreach($users as $user)
{
    foreach($data->toArray() as $dataRows) 
    { 
        if($user->admin ==0) 
        {
            $Data[]= 
                [
                'user_id' => $user->id, 
                'avatar' => 'avatar.png',
                'about' => $dataRows['description'] 
                ];
        }
    }
}
profile::insert($Data);
```

It loops through each user and assigns all the dataRows to each user. please help

Comment: Can you phrase the question more clearly?

Comment: Where do you initialize `$Data`? Is there an error? What is the problem you encounter?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: No error is returned, data is added to the database, however, lets say for example user_id of 1 is added to the database all 58 dataRows are assigned to the user_id of 1 and repeats this 58 times for the same user and when it is done, it goes to the second user and does the same thing.

Comment: That is what you can expect from nested loops.  You will need to synchronously iterate both data sources.  Are both arrays "indexed" by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your users array is indexed and your row data is an indexed array of associative arrays, you can marry-up/sync the data with a single loop using the shared index (`$i`).

```
$users = User::all();
$rows = $data->toArray();
foreach ($users as $i => $user) {
    if (!$user->admin) {
        $Data[]= 
            [
            'user_id' => $user->id, 
            'avatar' => 'avatar.png',
            'about' => isset($rows[$i]['description']) ? $rows[$i]['description'] : 'default'
            ];
    }
}
profile::insert($Data);
```

p.s. It may be advisable (depending on your data) to check that the corresponding `$row` data exists with `isset()` before trying to access the value.

Comment: i tried with the above code and it is throwing this error
Undefined offset: 57

Comment: You will need to add `&& isset($rows[$i]['description'])` after `!user->admin` but this means that users without descriptions will be omitted from the INSERT process. ...so this then raises more questions about your task...  How are you able to blindly merge these two data sets confidently?  How do you know you _should be_ combining a given userid with a given description?  The undefined offset means you have fewer descriptions than users.

Comment: for this part, it returns true or false
'about' => $rows[$i]['description'] 
it doesn't return the description

Comment: Did you receive the url

Comment: Managed to get it to work. Thank so much man. do you have a Skype address?